# ScrollView scrolls when Spinner is clicked

Tags: java, android, scrollview, spinner

I have a AppCompatSpinner in a ScrollView, the Spinner has 24 items.

**Problem:** When I click the Spinned the page scrolls down to put the Spinner on the top, to make space to show the dropdown menu.

**Question:** How do I make the page not scroll when the Spinner is clicked? If the Spinner is on the bottom of the screen the dropdown should appear above it, instead of scrolling down to appear bellow.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:id="@+id/mSpinner"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

Comment: I think the problem may be due to the layout that you are using to set the spinner dropdown options